# Unable to view user profiles when logged out (Meteor&Iron Router)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've built a user profile page for an app that I'm developing, the page works fine when an user is logged in, but when nobody is logged in the templates are empty. My goal is that anyone (even if it isn't registered in the app) is able to see the user profiles.

Here is the code:

Publication:

```
Meteor.publish('singleUser', function(userId) {
    if (this.userId) {
        var findById = Meteor.users.find(userId);
        return findById.count() ? findById : 'undefined';
    }
    return [];
 });
```

Router:

```
this.route('user_profile', {
    path: '/users/:_id',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('singleUser', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function() { 
        return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.params._id}); 
    }
});
```

Profile template:

```
<template name="user_profile">
    <h4>Username</h4>
    <p>{{username}}</p>
    <h4>User since:</h4>
    <p>{{createdAtFormatted}}</p>                   
</template>
```

Profile helpers:

```
Template.user_profile.helpers({
    createdAtFormatted: function(){
        return  moment(this.createdAt).fromNow();
    }   
});
```

I don't know what's missing in my code.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you publishing data for a single user? Don't you want to publish all user profiles? Why do you check for `this.userId`? I thought that you do not want it to be necessary that the user is logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it - you just need to fix the publish function. Your approach of only publishing the necessary user when you navigate to the profile page is correct.

Inside of a publish function, `this.userId` refers to the calling user's id. Because a client which hasn't logged in does not have a `userId`, it stands to reason that your publish function will return `[]` and the client will be unable to render the profile page. The rest of your publish function is unnecessary - it should return a cursor and not have to handle every possibility of data not being found. I think you want something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('userForProfilePage', function(userId) {
  check(userId, String);
  return Meteor.users.find(userId, {
    fields: {createdAt: 1, username: 1}
  });
});
```

Note the following:

- I used an explicit name for the function to clearly identify what I'm doing. I find `userForProfilePage` more clear than `singleUser`, but this is a matter of taste. Be sure to change your subscribe as appropriate.
- I used a simple [check](http://docs.meteor.com/#check) on the `userId` input. This validates that it is a string and not undefined. You can add more sophisticated checks as needed.
- Only if the check passed, will we return a cursor for the `userId`. The documents returned by the cursor will only contain the `_id`, `createdAt`, and `username` fields (this is done for security).

Comment: I wish all SO answers were written as well as this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure, whether you want to show all users' profiles or only a profile of one user, because if you are logged out the system will not know which user it is currently talking to. I assume this, because you said that you want to "see the user profiles".

Try this:

```
Meteor.publish('allUsers', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

You could also use `Meteor.methods()`.

```
Meteor.methods({
    allUsers: function () {
        return Meteor.users.find();
    }
});
```

And do not forget to wrap your template into a `{{#each allUsers}}{{/each}}` block.

Edit: Concerning security issues, map the values before passing them to the client.

```
Meteor.methods({
    allUsers: function () {
        return Meteor.users.find().fetch().map(function(user) {
            return {
                "name": user.username,
                "createdAt": user.createdAt
            };
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Uhh... doesn't this publish all users' e-mail addresses, resume tokens, etc.?

Comment: Yes, this is a potential security risk. If you want to get only the names, for example, then you have to extract that information on the server side. See my added example for clarification. I missed that point because it did not directly relate to the question, but thank you for mentioning it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My goal is to create a profile page for each user (/users/:_id), I'm going to test your suggestion

Comment: So should each user see all the other users' names on his profile page or not? If not, you would have to do it slightly different. Using `Metheor.methods()` could work for you in both cases, though.

Comment: I want that each user (and any person who visits the app but isn't registered) can view a page of each user with the {{username}} and {{createdAtFormatted}}

Comment: Yes, okay, that is what I thought. Don't forget to add `{{createdAtFormatted}}` to the mapping function via `user.createdAdd`. I edited my example.

Comment: Short hint: Don't forget to put your code into ´´ even in the comments to highlight it correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your solution but it doesn't work, the user profile page is empty. The template is supposed to stay like this? "<template name="allUsersProfile">
 {{#each allUsers}}
  {{> user_profile}}
 {{/each}}
</template> 
"

Comment: No, actually, you have to adjust the template. Also, `Meteor.methods()` is asynchronous, so that for the sake of reactivity you would have to use `Session` variables. Is your problem still unsolved?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I adopted the solution proposed by David Weldon, since I only needed to update the publish function.